# Are these black pods something to do with wasps?

Tags: identification, trees, wasps

I have a tree that is swarming with wasps. I cannot see a nest but assume there is one somewhere. I also noticed the tree is covered in patches of black pod types things:
[image]
Are the two things related? If not, what could these pods be?

This is in the south of the UK.

Comment: It would help a lot if you could say where you are located (roughly, that is), say whether this is a fig tree or similar, and take a penknife and lift up one of those black bumps and see if you can see anything underneath.

Comment: @ColinBeckingham ah yes, sorry for the oversight. I am in the southern half of the uk. I don’t think it’s a fig tree (but don’t know what tree it actually is). I can’t get too close to the bumps due to the aforementioned wasps.

Comment: You might be able to approach the tree successfully at dusk when the wasps go home. But don't take any unreasonable risks. The information sought is whether there is an insect living under the black bump. If you can get one and examine it under a lens then there might be a critter or eggs.